# Passing value from child form to parents form in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have one Delphi form A and it has menu which is calling another form B.
Form B has one procedure which is filling the couple of text fields after some calculation
on Formshow event.

I need that calculated field value in form A. What should be right approach for it.

Thanks,
Shazeb

Comment: Maybe `A.CalcResultFromB := B.CalculatedField;`? If you need something else, you need to improve your question and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

As I understand what you mean by "form A calling form B" is that form A call FormB.ShowModal.

You should replace that ShowModal call by a call to a new function in FormB. That function will call ShowModal and then return the calculated field.

Comment: I will add one example of it. original one is too complicated to share. Thanks for your response